# Why is after unserialize there is text "1" after array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

Sorry for my bad English before. I wanna ask why is after unserialize from my database, there is a text "1" after array. Look picture for detail:

[my database (the data is serialized)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMdKG.png)

[output of after unserialize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcgFv.png)

```
<div class="form-group">
                                                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Dokumen Pendukung:</label>
                                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                                            <p class="form-control-static"> <?php echo print_r(unserialize($supportDocument)); ?> </p>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
```

I have to try and check my code, there is no suspicious code. please help me.. Thanks.

```
public function addProposal($DocumentSupport) {
    try {

        $stmt = $this->connect->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_proposal(supportDocument)VALUES(:supportDocument)");



        $stmt->bindParam(":supportDocument", serialize($DocumentSupport));


        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt;

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Code please....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please always provide source code, error messages and other textual information as inline plain text rather than external pictures. Text is searchable, reusable and normally easier to read.

Comment: You need to post your code if any of us are to help you....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing the return value of [print_r()](http://php.net/print_r):

```
echo print_r(unserialize($supportDocument));
```

and, as documented, it returns `true`:

> When the `return` parameter is `TRUE`, this function will return a string. Otherwise, the **return value is `TRUE`**.

... which, when [converted to string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting), prints as `1`:

> A boolean `TRUE` value is converted to the string `"1"`. Boolean `FALSE` is
>   converted to `""` (the empty string). This allows conversion back and
>   forth between boolean and string values.

You should get rid of the `echo`:

```
print_r(unserialize($supportDocument));
```

You can also switch to [var_dump()](http://php.net/var_dump), which produces output that's more precise (for instance, it won't convert booleans to empty strings):

```
var_dump(unserialize($supportDocument));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just delete "echo"  from the code.